# Ascii-art graphs in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, charts

I have a text file that represents the runtime of a specific script, with each line representing one run:

```
141
124
156
204
498
512
444
374
189
120
143
132
```

One can see that the section that I pointed out represents a spike in the script runtime. Is there any package which will make an ascii-art graph out of this data, which could be viewed with cat or vim? I could write a script which, when given a terminal width, split the file into `lineCount / terminalWidth` chunks, average them, and then by column make a graph of the data. However, if there already exists such a package then I'd love to know about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Same as this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123378/command-line-unix-ascii-based-charting-plotting-tool)

Comment: Can't you cook up a simple script to output something like [this](http://bennuttall.com/ascii-bar-charts/)?

Comment: @Praveen: thank you, I had no idea that gnuplot could output ascii graphs. Nice!

Comment: @Karan: Doing the bars vertically is trivial, I would prefer something vertical. I could write it myself, but if the software already exists (apparently it does: gnuplot) then I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stackoverflow has a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123378/command-line-unix-ascii-based-charting-plotting-tool). As I cannot mark this Superuser question as a dupe of the Stackoverflow question, I'll summarise here: The application that can make an ascii-art graph out of the data is gnuplot.

```
gnuplot> set terminal dumb
gnuplot> plot "runtime.txt"
```