# Plot the data collected by sar in ASCII

Tags: linux, logging, io

`isag` in an  "Interactive System Activity Grapher" that "displays the system activity data stored in a binary data file by a previous `sar`".

How do I view the data stored by `sar` in ASCII on a Linux console?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `sar` you probably have `gnuplot` which

- supports [ASCII output](https://superuser.com/questions/489518/ascii-art-graphs-in-linux). ([Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123378/command-line-unix-ascii-based-charting-plotting-tool))
- can be [used with `sar`](http://aionica.computerlink.ro/2011/02/visualize-sar-reports-with-awk-and-gnuplot/).  ([Example 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-gnuplot/))

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising, but how would I have to use it on `sar -d -p`